# DNS Record to "redirect" from old server to new server

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

I have a question regarding DNS:

I have the following setup:

```
srv-old.example.com | Host(A) | 192.168.1.2 | timestamp
srv-new.example.com | Host(A) | 192.168.1.3 | static
```

can I just add another static A-Record like the following to achive, that all requests to srv-old.example.com will redirected to srv-new.example.com:

```
srv-old.example.com | Host(A) | 192.168.1.3 | static
```

so in summary i will have

```
srv-old.example.com | Host(A) | 192.168.1.2 | timestamp
srv-new.example.com | Host(A) | 192.168.1.3 | static 
srv-old.example.com | Host(A) | 192.168.1.3 | static
```

Or will this lead to a 50/50 chance to land on the new server when calling srv-old.example.com?
I already tried to edit the already existing non-static A-Record of srv-old.example.com, but it got updated after 1 day (i think by DHCP-Server).

The difficulty is, that srv-old needs to exist some more weeks, so i just cant take it offline and deleting the non-static A-Record will bring nothing in my opinion, because it will be recreated after one day.

I thought about a CNAME-Record like this too:

```
srv-old.example.com | CNAME | srv-new.example.com
```

But i think this will cause the same Problem to have a 50/50 Chance to land on the old or new server

Does anyone of you have a hint for me?
(A simple redirect 301 on the old webserver is no option at the moment)

Comment: Change IP settings on srv-old from DHCP to static and disable DNS record updating. Then remove the old record again.

Comment: Thanks. The IP of server-old was already static. I disabled the DNS record updating in the network adapter tab of the server an then deleted dynamic A-Record of srv-old and next created a new static record for srv-old to point to the IP of srv-new. However, on the next day, the static(!) entry i created was overwritten with the IP of srv-old...

My solution: to rename the srv-old to e.g. srv-old-old and set the static A-Record back how i need it (pointing to the IP of srv-new). In case the srv-old reregister itself in DNS, it does it with an other name and will not overwrite the A-Record.

Answer (score 0):

I would switch to [Round Robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) until it was time to deprecate old server and then remove old servers A record.

> srv.example.com | Host(A) | 192.168.1. | static

> srv.example.com | Host(A) | 192.168.1.3 | static

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i think this is not possible in my example. With round robin, half of the requests will land on the old server, with old Web GUI and old Informations. I need to make sure that 100% of the requests land on the new server

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do HTTP redirects with DNS only. You can point `srv-old.example.com` to another server (possibly light temporary VM) which would send `301` to the new server.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i already know that. I already set up an additional virtual host (apache) on the srv-new, to redirect request coming via srv-old.example.com. But i first need to "redirect" the name resolution so the call of srv-old.example.com will point to the IP of srv-new.example.com (via DNS). But my problem atm is, that in DNS a dynamic A-Record for srv-old.example.com already exists (with the old IP), which will be upadted every 24h. I need to stop srv-old to register himself to the DNS to set a static A-Record pointing to the IP of srv-new, without round robin effect.